# Passport session getting expired behind Nginx proxy - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, nginx, passport.js

I am using `PassportJS` to authenticate my users and i have set it up behind an `Nginx` proxy. After about 10-15 mins of inactivity `req.isAuthenticated()` is returning `false`.

I have initialized `Passport` like this

```
// Initialize Passport
require('./auth/passport')(passport);
app.use(session({ store: new RedisStore({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379, client: client,ttl :  260}), secret: config.passportSessionSecret , proxy: true , cookie: {maxAge : 36000000} , saveUninitialized: true , resave: true }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

and my `nginx` proxy is like this

```
location / {
            auth_basic "Private Property";
            auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.httppassword;
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
```

I am using `Let's encrypt SSL` and also secured the server using `Nginx HTTP Password`.

Also there are many users logging in via the same `Nginx Password`

Am i doing something wrong.

**FOLLOW THIS! IT WORKS** https://gist.github.com/nikmartin/5902176

Answer (score 0):

Add rolling option.

Example:

```
app.use(session({ store: new RedisStore({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379, client: client,ttl :  260}), secret: config.passportSessionSecret , proxy: true , cookie: {maxAge : 36000000} , saveUninitialized: true , resave: true, rolling: true }));
```

Comment: Replace  cookie: {maxAge : 36000000} by cookie:{_expires : 36000000}

Comment: Hey, Solved it. It was my `nginx` proxy headers problem.